# Is ef6 compatible with the most recent version of mariadb?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.8, mariadb-11

My application is using currently using .netframework 4.8.1, ef6 v 6.4.4, mysql.data.entityframework as the relevant packages, our database is currently using mysql 5.7, I was able to get app working with mysql 8 but would like to see if it is possible to use mariadb.

When i try to use the app with mariadb I get this error. Unexpected connection state. When using a wrapping provider ensure that the StateChange event is implemented on the wrapped DbConnection.